# Strange behavior with input type="hidden" and prop("checked", true)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stumbled upon this by accident, and I'm wondering if its a bug or intended behaviour. I set a checked on an input type="hidden" which I thought was not possible. But depending on the used jQuery selector this field is then returned or not returned.

HTML:

```
<form>
  <div>Checkbox: <input class="test" type="checkbox" name="check" value="1" /></div>
  <div>Hidden: <input class="test" type="hidden" name="check" value="1" /></div>
  <div><input id="button" type="button" value="run test" /></div>
  <div>Results:</div>
  <div id="resultA"><strong>$('.test:checked')</strong><br /></div>
  <div id="resultB"><strong>$('.test:checked[value=1]')</strong><br /></div>
  <div id="resultC"><strong>$('.test:checked[value="1"]')</strong><br /></div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('.test').prop('checked', true);

    $('.test:checked').each(function() {
      $('#resultA').append($(this).attr('type') + ' - checked<br />');
    });

    $('.test:checked[value=1]').each(function() {
      $('#resultB').append($(this).attr('type') + ' - checked<br />');
    });

    $('.test:checked[value="1"]').each(function() {
      $('#resultC').append($(this).attr('type') + ' - checked<br />');
    });
  });
});
```

Above example as a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m5fatj8q/6/

> ResultA: only returns the checkbox.
>
> ResultB: returns both the checkbox and hiddden field!
>
> ResultC: only returns the checkbox.

---

**My questing is:**

Why does resultB return the hidden field? And is this a bug or intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute selector `[value=1]` is not valid; the value you're matching against in an attribute selector either has to be a string (denoted with quotes, as per your 3rd option) or a [CSS identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) which

> cannot start with a digit.

That's why the behaviour differs between 2 and 3.

The reason it then differs between 1 and 2 must be down to a bug in [Sizzle](https://sizzlejs.com/), the selector engine that jQuery uses internally, not correctly handling invalid selectors.  If you instead use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), you get

> '.test:checked[value=1]' is not a valid selector.

---

I'm by no means an expert in the Sizzle source code, but I think the issue is a combination of [their definition of an attribute](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js#L85):

```
// "Attribute values must be CSS identifiers [capture 5] or strings [capture 3 or capture 4]"
```

and [here](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js#L1141):

```
// Move the given value to match[3] whether quoted or unquoted
match[3] = ( match[3] || match[4] || match[5] || "" ).replace( runescape, funescape );
```

which would appear to just use the value given, no matter whether it was quoted or not.  This is then compounded by [the check for `:checked`](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js#L1515):

```
return (nodeName === "input" && !!elem.checked) || (nodeName === "option" && !!elem.selected);
```

Which seems to only look to make sure it's an `<input>` element, and [not specifically](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#selector-checked) a checkbox or radio button.